# Submitting apps automatically to app store

Tags: iphone, templates, app-store, account

I'm planning to crate a service that among other things creates an iPhone app based on a template and submits it to the AppStore almost without human intervention. 
Is that allowed by apple?

Some similar startups now require users to use their own developers account (which costs $100 and will not be paid by my users).

In principle I don't see why not, as regular developers are allowed to submit their customer's apps. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not allowed by apple. As that would be using a single developer account to submit apps, from someone different that the person that purchased the account (you in this case).

Besides if they can submit anything, if someone submits something inappropriate under your name, it will be your problem not theirs.

Furthermore I am pretty sure your clients, would want their name in the AppStore for their app and not yours.

Comment: Can I work around this by putting someone who manually uploads the app to the app store after reviewing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not allowed by Apple.  Even if it was, the apps would be under your name so any in app purchase would be put into your bank account (cha-ching $$$)